# Adding picture from disk not working after fail with adding from web

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

Like in topic. Here are steps:

1. **Paste link (which can be broken) to image form. We got error:**
   [image]
2. **Change mind and select option** `From my computer`:
   [image]

Like you see file input **disappear**.

---

*Additional information:*

```
Google Chrome:      25.0.1364.97 (Oficjalna wersja 183676) m
Operating System:   Windows 8
WebKit:             537.22 (@143379)
JavaScript:         V8 3.15.11.15
Flash:              11.6.602.171
Client:             Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22
```

Comment: I had this happening to me too. But I thought it might just be Opera's engine.

Comment: Can I know why someone downvote this question/bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.